# Articles with proper nouns as adjectives

Tags: articles, definite-articles, proper-nouns

Do I need to use articles in front of proper nouns that are used as **adjectives**?

Examples:

"I joined [the] Warp Engine team."

"I want to share [the] Warp Engine roadmap with you."

Comment: Usually, yes. *I joined **the** [green|fast|Smithsonian|Apollo|Johnson] team.* Unless it is posessive: *I joined Johnson's team.*

Comment: Not in certain cases, eg  _She's a member of [the] Boarshurst Brass Band_ /  _He's a member of [the?] Garforth Working Mens Club_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - But your examples are true proper nouns, not regular nouns modified by proper nouns used as adjectives.  The OP's example's are of regular nouns modified by proper noun-adjectives, and the article is determined by the noun.

Comment: @Drew - That's not a duplicate.  The referenced question does not discuss using proper nouns as adjectives for common nouns.

Comment: Yes, since there is only one  "Warp Engine" you need the definite article "the". Note though, that "Warp Engine" is **not** an adjective; it is a proper noun functioning as modifier (there is a difference!).

Comment: @BillJ - You need the "the", but not because the "modifier" is a proper noun.  You need it because the nouns are "team" and "roadmap".  You would still need the article if it were the "Warp Engines team".

Comment: @HotLicks Those are not being used as adjectives. They're being used as nouns, attributive nouns. That does not make them an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule with articles, when applied to adjective-modified common nouns, is that you use (or not) the article you'd use if the adjectives were not present (with the usual caveat about *a/an*).

So, since you would say "I joined the team" you would likewise say "I joined the Warp Engine team."  The fact that the adjective "Warp Engine" is developed from a proper noun is irrelevant.

On the other hand, note that if "Warp Engine Team" is considered a proper noun then the article might or might not be used -- the use of articles with proper nouns is a bit idiosyncratic.

Answer (score -3):

It varies. On a case-by-case basis.

> We went up on **the** Empire State Building.
>
> We were in Central Park this afternoon.
>
> You'll need to walk over **the** Brooklyn Bridge.
>
> You should spend some time in Washington Square Park.

Comment: Re-read the question *carefully*.

Comment: @HotLicks Re-read the answer with a similar degree of care.

Comment: You're answering a different question.  What part of "used as adjectives" do you not understand?

Comment: @HotLicks None of them.